# Ubuntu installer has no installation option/ internal ssd not displayed

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I recently purchased a Dell XPS 15 model 9550, but I am having issues installing Ubuntu on it. I have burn the iso to an external hard drive and booted the installer from the drive, however I was not able to get any installation options from the installer such as dual boot with windows, etc.

[image]

When running gpart and the command sudo fdisk -l, I am getting back my external hard drive information only.

[image]

I have tried advices like turning off fast boot and hibernate in windows, booting with secure boot disabled, but still end up with the same result. Help?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

I used os-prober to find where my windows OS is located, which is on /dev/nvme0n1
Then I used gpart to open that and the installer now detects the drive.